# How i can return the token after the user register complete?

Tags: node.js, adonis.js

I'm making a api to register users and i like to return in the json response the user and the jwt token.

Actually this is my function:

```
initializeCreate( {request} ){
    const data = request.only(["username", "password", "permission", "status"])
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        user.create(data, function(err, resp, body) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(JSON.parse(body))
            }
        })
    })
}

createUser({ auth }){

var initializePromise = initializeCreate();
initializePromise.then(function(result) {
    const token = await auth.attempt(result.username, result.password)
    return token     
}, function(err) {
    console.log(err);
})}
```

I suppose that i have to wait the event User.create() finish to make the auth.attempt, so i create this promise, but this is the better way to do this? There's a way that i make this in only 1 function?
Actually i'm receiving this error:

> Unexpected token const token = await auth.attempt(result.username,
>   result.password)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.generate(user)` - [documentation](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/authentication#_generateuser_jwtpayload_jwtoptions)

```js
const user = await User.find(1)

const token = await auth.generate(user)
```

or `.attempt(uid, password)` - [documentation](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/authentication#_attemptuid_password_2)

```js
const token = await auth.attempt(uid, password)
```

> I suppose that i have to wait the event User.create() finish to make
>   the auth.attempt, so i create this promise, but this is the better way
>   to do this?

Yes. You need to use `await`. like :

```js
await user.create(...)
```

(And now you can put everything in a function)

You can use try/catch :

```js
async login({ auth, response, request }) {
        const data = request.only(['email', 'password'])
        try {
            await auth.check()
            return response.status(200).send({ message: 'You are already logged!' })
        } catch (error) {
            try {
                return await auth.attempt(data.email, data.password)
            } catch (error) {
                return response.status(401).send({ message: error.message })
            }
        }
    }
```

*Sample code for a [personal project](https://gitlab.com/CrBast/website/blob/develop/website/app/Controllers/Http/api/AuthController.js)*